# running javascript functions using wallaby's execute_script does not work

Tags: phantomjs, elixir, phoenix-framework, wallaby

### System

OSX v10.13.4 / Elixir v1.6.5 / OTP 19 / Phoenix 1.3.2 / Wallaby 0.19.2 / PhantomJS 2.1

### Issue

The following code works in testing

```
execute_script(session, "localStorage.setItem('test', 'foo'); return localStorage.getItem('test');")
```

However, if I call the exact same methods which are in a function called `get_test()` inside `app.js` of my Phoenix App

```
  function get_test() {
    localStorage.setItem('test', 'foo'); 
    return localStorage.getItem('test');
  }

  window.get_test = get_test
```

And run the following in my test suite

```
execute_script(session, "return get_test();")
```

I get `{:error, :obscured}`

I have tried with selenium on the same code and it works. However, for some reason, with PhantomJS it does not seem to find functions that have been created by ourselves.

*Am I missing something?* I did notice in the tests for execute_script in wallaby there are no tests that call specifically created functions.

https://github.com/keathley/wallaby/blob/master/integration_test/cases/browser/execute_script_test.exs

A similar test 
https://github.com/keathley/wallaby/blob/master/integration_test/cases/browser/local_storage_test.exs

of which I added the following to the `local_storage_test` to verify I was not going nuts

```
@function_script """
  function get_tester() {
    localStorage.setItem('tester', 'foo');
    return localStorage.getItem('tester');
  }

  return get_tester();
"""

session
  |> visit("index.html")
  |> execute_script(@function_script, fn(value) -> send self(), {:callback, value} end)

assert_received {:callback, "foo"}
```

and it passed. This is clearly something wrong with my app. Or Phantom config perhaps.

**UPDATE:**

Although not mentioned directly - I have narrowed this down to *libsodim* not loading properly with *phantomjs*. Back to basics on the debugging. Nothing wrong with the JS written. On a positive note, I now have a whole library of tests which is cool and some cool tools for testing.

Comment: ...or spelling. `execute_script(session, "reutrn get_test();")` seems to have `return` misspelled.

Comment: sorry for the typo and nice spot, but it is not the issue. I am wondering if its a timing thing is the page loaded properly